# Is it possble to get all objects from memory?

Tags: java

How to get all objects present in memory?

```
public static void main( String[] arg ){
    MyClass object1 = new MyClass();
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal();
    Object obj = new Object();
    List allObjects = getAllObjects(); // return  object1, bd, obj        
    ;
    ;
    ;  

}
```

Comment: This is an unusual question, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Gennadiy: i would like to get all objects in memory, and then save them all as yaml.

Comment: I think you can collect them inside a class and serialize it when needed?

Comment: @Rakesh: If you wish to save only your objects you can instrument them and catch their reference at construct time, then go over the refs and save them. It would be unwise to save the entire JDK state though.

Comment: @Alex: i think you are on the right path. But how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest is getting a heap dump by VisualVM. JDK also includes related tools, as the [jmap tool](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html).

Answer (score 2):

I fear there is no easy answer to do this during runtime, either you use Instrumentation 
[How can I access Java heap objects without a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384228/how-can-i-access-java-heap-objects-without-a-reference)
or write an agent 
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html